# Copy files from embedded Linux to Windows via serial cable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use Python 2.7/PySerial scripts to run tests on devices with an embedded Linux. Due to a recent software change, the Linux box generates a number of log files in .csv format. I need to fetch them. I can't enable any server features in the Linux; I only have a serial connection.

I can of course read the file content out and capture it as text, but this is clumsy and unreliable - I would rather copy the files. Two days of search, and I'm still clueless (Generic problem with me!).

Any hints, please? Please be gentle - this is my first question... :)

Comment: No, you can't because **I can't enable any server features in the Linux**. If you don't have access to the file system, you can't. The serial port user must have previously received file access. You can read files (from an inside-defined application) with a Telnet or similar protocol (with the system's predefined commands). Linux boxes do not support Linux commands (restricted access, prohibited commands).

Comment: I do have full access to the file system: the serial connection is to a root terminal, so to speak. I can execute all the standard Linux commands. But all the server functions are stripped out.

Comment: use **winscp** !

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a serial terminal you can use `sz` (part of `lrzsz`) to send the files via ZModem. Simply use a serial comm program on the other side (Hyperterminal?) that understands ZModem and the files can be transferred over.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you very much for the proposed solutions. Unfortunately, neither work (I can not enable anything extra on the Linux box), and they are both outside the desired Python environment.
I think it's a kludge, but i'll have to ask for a

```
cat logfile
```

as a text string, and attempt to catch the prompt at the end.

Thank you for your time and effort.